# Why does my rails localhost server continue when I stop it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using Aptana Studio and have 2 terminals up, one for commands, the other for the server. When I run the rails server (`rails s`), do whatever I need and than stop it. It stays up as if I didn't turn it off. I'm using a `PostgreSQL` database on Windows 7. Anyone else have this issue?

Maybe it's not a rails issue but a Windows one. If it's the latter, how would I fixed this?

Comment: Is Aptana running it before and after you try to run it in the terminal?

Comment: @JimDeville No it's not. If I exit out of Aptana all together, it still is up.

Comment: How are you stopping the server?

Comment: @Beerlington In the terminal I started in, I push Ctr + C like it says to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not rails issue it also happen to me on ubuntu 12.10 what i do if i want to restart rails server is to kill the process manually in ubuntu

```
   ps -x | grep rails 
   sudo kill -9 "id of the process"
```

in windows it will be easier just kill the process from the task manager

Comment: OK, Thanks, I'll keep this in mind. I'll figure out how to kill the process in windows command. I looked at the Task Manager but couldn't find anything on LocalHost.